# Kubernetes service with different port types (NodePort / ClisterIP)

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to expose service ports with different policies like NodePort or ClusterIP.

For example we have

- some public XMPP API that should be accessible for end users
- internal cluster API to communicate with other micro-services

Right now I can create different services of types NodePort and ClisterIP but is it possible to handle it with single k8s 'Service'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using two distinct services each of its own type is the right way to do it, and there is no harm/overhead in doing it like this